# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_googlemaps'

Tags: python, flask, google-maps-api-3, pip, virtualenv

I am building my first ever Flask app and I created a virtual environment and ran `pip install flask_googlemaps` as per the instructions for [flask-googlemaps](https://pypi.org/project/flask-googlemaps/), however I keep returning the `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_googlemaps'` error.

Below is a screenshot that will hopefully help.

[ModuleNotFoundError with pip list and import statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5crl.png)

I am new to Python/Flask so I have tried researching fixes but I am still lost as all of the likely errors don't seem to be applicable for me. For instance my virtual environment has been activated; `pip list` shows the module; no other modules are having issues; I set the Python interpreter (Python 3.11.3); and I also tried running `export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/path/to/my/project/"` as I saw this in [this popular article by Giorgos Myrianthous](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-fix-modulenotfounderror-and-importerror-248ce5b69b1c) but still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

From the screenshot it looks like your entire project is inside the venv folder?

Try moving all your projects folders and files out of the `venv` folder.

All that should be in the venv folder is `lib`, `bin`, `include` and `pyvenv.cfg`